# Visual Studio new Project with wrong git repository

Tags: visual-studio, github

When I create a new project, I connect it with the git source from another existing project, this one is totally new and I don't know why it takes the sources control from the other ones without asking or anything.

For example, I have my project "A" on my computer, connected with git, today I tried to create project "B", and from the beginning, it connects with the git from the project "A", and says that I have tons of changes.

How could I avoid that o change it?

Comment: This question needs more details. To start: Where is project B located? Could it be that your projects are nested?

Comment: yes check the paths where both are located and what there origins are

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the `.git` folder or you can simply change the repository URL as below
Changing a remote repository's URL
The git remote set-url command changes an existing remote repository URL.

> ```
> git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a `.git` folder in your new project directory. Try deleting that and it should work when you connect it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I know how to solve it. For some reason, VSC (*Visual Studio Code*) has the wrong path for the git folder.

**How to fix it:**

1.
When you hover your mouse here:

[image]

you will see that path (mine pointed to the whole desktop). Delete it in explorer.

2.
In my case, that was all I needed to do. After that VSC found a proper git file.